# Error while running forloop on python split function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code below where The user can add a English text numbers separated by a `,`

**example input:** three hundred thirty five, six million five hundred one, three

**output should be:**  335, 6000501, 3

below is my code

```
print("Please type your number below")
value = input("")
string = ""
for unit_value in value.split(", "):
    string = str(challenge1(unit_value.lower()))   #function challenge1 code below (In my code it comes before )
    print(string)
```

**My output is as below** Why is the code not running after the 1st loop

```
335             #I can switch the order no matter what number I put 1st it shows
None            #The 2nd and 3rd loop always show none no matter what the number 
None
```

I added print statements to see if everything was good and it is

```
print("Please type your number below")
value = input("")
string = ""
for unit_value in value.split(", "):
    print(unit_value)   #extra print added to see unit_value
    string = str(challenge1(unit_value.lower()))
    print(unit_value)

output is correct as below 

three hundred thirty five
six million five hundred one
three
```

Below are the details of the function challenge1

```
def challenge1(single_word, complete_number={}):
    if not complete_number:
        uniques = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
                   "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]


        teners = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

        big_nums = ["hundred", "thousand", "million"]    


        for index, word in enumerate(uniques):
            complete_number[word] = (1, index)
        for index, word in enumerate(teners):
            complete_number[word] = (1, index * 10)
        for index, word in enumerate(big_nums):
            complete_number[word] = (10 ** (index * 3 or 2), 0)


        current = 0
        result = 0

        for word in single_word.split():

            if word not in complete_number:
                print("Input is not a number. Please see the examples of how to enter number /n six  /n negative seven"
                      " hundred twenty nine, /n one million one hundred one")


            scale, increment = complete_number[word]
            current = current * scale + increment
            if scale > 100:
                result += current
                current = 0
     return result + current
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so the default `None` is returned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It works in the 1st loop why does the same function not work in later loops

Comment: What works? `return` ends a function, so *don't put it in the loop*.

Comment: @ MartijnPieters 
`def function(x):
    y = x * 2
    return y` but if I add `function(x)` to the loop it runs 3 times `function(x)` has return in it too

Comment: @JayShankarGupta If I don't add the return statement what do I add in the function

Comment: @JayShankarGupta I am sorry I did not understand. Can you edit my code or put the suggestion in a answer

Comment: add `complete_number.clear() ` before your return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited your function you need to clear() your dictionary as it's static declaration. The dictionary you declared is static it's not recreating on every call so you need to clear it or write like below :**

```
def challenge1(single_word): 
   complete_number={}
```

**Corrected code:**

```
def challenge1(single_word, complete_number={}):
    if not complete_number:
        uniques = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
                   "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]


        teners = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

        big_nums = ["hundred", "thousand", "million"]

        negative = ["negative"]    

        for index, word in enumerate(uniques):
            complete_number[word] = (1, index)
        for index, word in enumerate(teners):
            complete_number[word] = (1, index * 10)
        for index, word in enumerate(big_nums):
            complete_number[word] = (10 ** (index * 3 or 2), 0)


        current = 0
        result = 0

        for word in single_word.split():

            if word not in complete_number:
                print("Input is not a number. Please see the examples of how to enter number /n six  /n negative seven"
                      " hundred twenty nine, /n one million one hundred one")


            scale, increment = complete_number[word]
            current = current * scale + increment
            if scale > 100:
                result += current
                current = 0
        complete_number.clear()
        return result + current
```

Comment: That worked Is it possible to explain why it wasn't working before in the answer too

Comment: added explanation you can check @SamirTendulkar

Comment: Oh!!! wow right, I should have noticed that.  three down votes but still worth it thank you so much for answering

Comment: Welcome @SamirTendulkar Happy to help you.

Comment: Actually I am looking for switching my current company So can you Give me any information about vacancies in you company. @SamirTendulkar

Comment: Your profile says you are in India I am in NY USA would you be looking to relocate